# ClassPathResource: File not found exception when running the jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources, classpath

I've written a java code which looks like below

```
String readFile(String schemaFileName) throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("abc/" + schemaFileName);
    return FileUtils.readFileToString(classPathResource.getFile(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

When I'm running from IntelliJ everything is working fine but when I deploy the app using created jar it gives following exception

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [abc/myfile] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/my_application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/abc/myfile
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:215) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

In my jar, I can see the directory

```
$ ll BOOT-INF/classes/abc/myfile
total 44
drwxrwxr-x 2 ganesh ganesh  4096 Jan 23 12:59 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 ganesh ganesh  4096 Jan 23 12:59 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ganesh ganesh 31735 Jan 23 12:59 myfile
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Because when packaged as a jar it isn't a file anymore. Use the `resource.getInputStream` to read the content instead the `getFile`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the comment. Can you elaborate that more. If you have some documentation/article you can share that as well.

Comment: When using `File` that should resolve to an actual file on the file system. This is the case when running from your IDE as that is running not from a JAR. When packaged as a jar this isn't the case hence it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `classpath*:my.config` if your `spring-context.xml` and `my.config` files are in different jars

Also, make sure you are using `resource.getInputStream()` not `resource.getFile()` when loading from inside a jar file.

More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#resources-classpath-wildcards)